# ffmpeg multiple task at once in one process id

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I wanna to run these conversion task at single ffmpeg process, but I don't know how do that.

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mkv output1.mp4
ffmpeg -i video2.mkv output2.mp4
ffmpeg -i video3.mkv output3.mp4
```

I have tried to use character "&" to separate the task like this,

```
string parameters = "-i video1.mkv output1.mp4 & -i video2.mkv output2.mp4 & -i video3.mkv output3.mp4";

var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
processInfo.Arguments = parameters;
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

using (var process = new Process())
{
   process.StartInfo = processInfo;
   process.Start();
   process.WaitForExit();
}
```

It's not working. And another separator like `&&` `|` `;` also doesn't work.

I have tried this code on cmd.exe :

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mkv output1.mp4 & ffmpeg -i video2.mkv output2.mp4 & ffmpeg -i video3.mkv output3.mp4
```

It produces 3 process id's where I don't want do that. I want single process that can execute 3 conversion at once. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: ffmpeg is a command line program. Each call produces a process. There's no way around that. Perhaps a better question would be "why do you need it to be a single process?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mkv -i video2.mkv -i video3.mkv -map 0 output1.mp4 -map 1 output2.mp4 -map 2 output3.mp4
```